# accessing client side jquery variable in server side groovy page

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, groovy

I have a variable in my JavaScript which contains the id of the clicked row in the master grid. I want to pass it to the groovy service page that handles my child grid so that it can filter the rows based on that id. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your javascript-based grid runs on the client, while the page is rendered server-side. Therefore, some communication must take place in order to instruct your application to filter rows based on what the user selects.

Grails uses the MVC architecture, this means that there is a controller that takes care of answering the requests generated from the client. To answer these requests, the Controller can make use of the Views (.gsp files). So when you call to the URL `controller/index` you may make use of an `index.gsp` view to render your page.

What you need to do is to make an [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to a controller method (e.g. `controller/getFilteredRows`) that gets as input the selected row (could be its `id`) and based on some logic fetches all the required information and sends them back to the client encoded for example using [JSON](http://json.org/).

Now the client knows the rows it has to display, hence you can update your grid.

Comment: i knew that this is the way to do that but the problem is- as you can see the url for the grid is passed as part of a hashmap //this.options.childParameters.collection.url. so i'm not sure how to pass the parameter thorugh the url here/make an ajax call